# How to get the Document which has MAX of error?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Db Operation:

```
db.error.aggregate([
{
    $group:{
      _id:'$Origin.SN',
      No_of_Error:{$sum:1},
      error:{ $first:'$error'},
      date:{ $first:'$timestamp.full'},
  }  
}
```

])

After performing this operation I got the below result. I want the document which has the highest error. Please tell me how to Write it.

```
 {
"_id" : "15580973",
"No_of_Error" : 1.0,
"error" : "No Error",
"date" : "Mon Feb 13 11:29:30 UTC 2017"
```

}

```
{
"_id" : "5700989",
"No_of_Error" : 3.0,
"error" : "Water missing",
"date" : "Mon Feb 13 10:38:48 UTC 2017"
```

}

```
{
"_id" : "15580969",
"No_of_Error" : 3.0,
"error" : "Water missing",
"date" : "Thu Feb 09 16:23:52 UTC 2017"
```

}

```
{
"_id" : "4500",
"No_of_Error" : 7.0,
"error" : "No Error",
"date" : "Tue Feb 07 09:46:30 UTC 2017"
```

}

```
{
"_id" : "15581316",
"No_of_Error" : 1.0,
"error" : "No Error",
"date" : "Tue Feb 07 12:04:19 UTC 2017"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort method. To get result in descending order.

```
db.error.aggregate([
{
    $group:{
      _id:'$Origin.SN',
      No_of_Error:{$sum:1},
      error:{ $first:'$error'},
      date:{ $first:'$timestamp.full'}
  },  { $sort : {"No_of_Error" : -1} } 
}

])
```

Comment: Try adding `{$limit:1}` as last stage to get the max error document.

Comment: @Subhakant would you like to post one sample document and above aggregate output. And expected output.